# How to send json commands to BLE device and get response of same commands in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I am new to BLE device integration. I have implemented code to connect with the BLE device and it's successfully connected but now I want to pass the custom commands to get data from that device.

Below is Json that needs to be passed to the BLE device.

#### Get the device battery level.

App to Device:

```
{"cmd": "getBatteryLevel"}
{"cmd":"setLight", "channel":"0", "brightness":100, "state":"ON"}
```

Device to App (OK Response):

```
{"cmd": "getBatteryLevel", "response":100}
{"cmd":"setLight", "channel":"0", "brightness":100, "state":"ON", "response":"OK"}
```

I have tried below. But it did not work.

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {
    
    guard let characteristics = service.characteristics else { return }
    
    for characteristic in characteristics {
        if characteristic.properties.contains(.write) && !isValueWritten {
            // Save the characteristic for later use
            self.characteristic = characteristic
            guard let data = self.viewModel.setBLELightCommand() else { return
                print("Invalid data")
            }
            
            peripheral.writeValue(data, for: characteristic, type: .withResponse)
        }
    }
}

func convertJsonDictToData(_ dict:[String:Any])->Data?{
    do {
        let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dict, options: .prettyPrinted)
        // here "jsonData" is the dictionary encoded in JSON data
        guard let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8), let data = jsonString.data(using: .utf8) else {
            return nil
        }
        return data
        
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return nil
    }
}

func setBLELightCommand()->Data?{
    let setLightCommand = [
        "cmd" : "setLight",
        "channel" : "0",
        "brightness" : "50",
        "state" : "ON"
    ]
    return convertJsonDictToData(setLightCommand)
}
```

Comment: When making data exchange between BLE devices you must send these by chunk because the size of packet is limited. Also for battery level there is a BLE characteristic than you can use to get device battery level.

Comment: What kind of BLE device are you trying to use? Do you have documentation on the services and characteristics? Have you tried using a generic BLE exploration tool such as [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nRF-Connect-for-mobile) to test the connection?

Comment: No I only have commands to read/write but I am able to connect by using the connect method of CoreBluetooth but now I want to run commands to get detail.

Comment: I'm asking because json is not a usual method to read or write from/to a BLE device. Have you tested the device using nRF Connect?

Comment: "But it did not work." In what way? Did you receive an error? Where? What error? Did the device behave incorrect? Did your code run at all? Your code does not match the spec you provided (it is related to getBatteryLevel but your code passes setLight). Does getBatteryLevel work? Passing integers as Strings is unusual. For example, is channel supposed to be `0` or `"0"`? Those are different things. What does the spec say? Can you provide a link to the spec. Most of debugging this will be "did you do exactly what the documentation says?" This is a custom protocol, so we can't guess.

Comment: @RobNapier, I have edited the above command and added more commands from the documentation. There are more than 10 commands so I just want that if any one command will work then will easy to Implement other.

Comment: The command takes `"brightness":100`, where brightness is an integer. You're sending a string.

Answer (score 0):

BLE devices typically do not work in the way you describe. Typically a BLE device publishes a number of values that can be read from it. Battery level could be one of those values. Each value is called a "characteristic", and you subscribe to changes to that characteristic. So in your case, you would subscribe to changes to the battery level, and your app gets notified each time the battery level changes.

That said, if your description is correct, then your device seems to use one characteristic as a text string to write commands to the device, and another string characteristic to be informed of responses. From the interface documentation, determine which characteristic those are.

Subscribe to notifications on the "read" characteristic. Your routine will be called every time that characteristic changes. Process the strings that you receive on that.

Then write your JSON string commands to the "write" characteristic (the one mentioned in the documentation; not just all of them that have "write" capability). Make sure the string is not longer than the maximum BLE string length.

Comment: Ok, I will try to pass small command first so that it should not exceed the maximum BLE string length.